# Ruby HAML add If Condition to each.do

Tags: ruby, salesforce, where-clause, each, haml

I have a haml ruby site that is pulling data from Salesforce.  What I need to be able to do is to set an if condition based on the productCode listed in SF.  The each.do establishes a loop to display the related data for each record in the loop.

The client would like productFamily specific pages.  So I need to loop through all items with a product code of GEA for one page and GFE for another page.

```
      .row
    .col-xs-12
      - @price_book.where(:productCode => GEA).each do |prod|

        .row
          .panel.panel-default
            .panel-body
              .col-xs-4
                %img{:src => "#{prod.productUrl}", :height => "200", :width => "150"}
```

When I attempt to run this I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::GEA): 
7:  
8:       .row 
9:         .col-xs-12 
10:           - @price_book.where(:productcode => GEA).each do |prod| 
11:  
12:             .row 
13:               .panel.panel-default
```

Thank You for your assistance, I am new to Ruby and modifying another Developers code.

Comment: What is `@price_book`? Where do you define it? What is `GEA`? Do you mean `"GEA"`?

Comment: @pricebook is calling code in the controller for that page.  No issues with that code, but it pulls back all items listed in the price book,

GEA is a product code on the pricebook. I would like the loop to only bring back items with a productCode of GEA,  I tried with quotes and got an error about where.

Comment: I am trying to follow this pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950402/if-condition-in-each-do-rails, but got the error listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to apply the if filter logic to the loop with the following modification to the code

```
    - @price_book.select{ |prod| prod[:productCode] == "GEA" }.each do |prod|
```

This returned only items from the price book with a product code of GEA

Answer (score 0):

If `@price_book` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, not just array of `YourModel` and `productcode` is String column of `YourModel` then you can call additional ActiveRecord methods like where:

```
@price_book.where(:productcode => 'GEA')
```

If GEA, GFE are not variables defined in view then values should be in quotes (double quotes) `'GEA'`, `"GFE"`.

---

You can put

```
= @price_book.inspect
```

in your template and get more info about it. Tell us what kind of object is `@price_book` and we will give you advice.

Comment: pricebook is calling a class in Salesforce that returns a set of records that meet the class criteria, so the list data comes from that system. @price_book, the logic however is in SF
    def get_products
    client = Restforce.new
    result = client.get '/services/apexrest/portal/pricebook/', :business_unit => ENV['BUSINESS_UNIT']
    # todo: handle error response
    puts "get pricebook body \n\n"
    puts result.body
    puts "\n"
    puts "get pricebook body productList \n\n"
    puts result.body.productList
    puts "\n"
    price_book = result.body.productList

Comment: I am not sue what ActiveRecord::Relation is.  can you define that for me?  Thank You

Comment: This is a section of the
    @price_book.inspect
     keyactivities="<h1>Key Actives:</h1><br>\r\n<b>A special combination of 19 unique bioactive ingredients work to actively support cytokines balance and enhance immune system health. Key chemistries include:</b>" productCode="GEA" productDescription="<b>Maximize your health and recovery. Balance your immune system and invest your body’s ultimate performance capabilities.*</b>

Comment: so it appears from this that productCode is coming over and "GEA" is a valid value.

Comment: @KellyPedrick It is not clear to me what is `@price_book`. Can you put in the template `= @price_book.class` and give us output?